# Running a CodeDeploy hook on just one instance in a group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to figure out how to use CodeDeploy to update our application on a group of instances. The documentation has gotten me through getting the files deployed, and making any tweaks as necessary (preserving config files, restarting processes, etc) using hooks.

I'm stuck on one requirement though. During a deployment, the application contains a MySQL script that needs to run against the database (RDS). I can create a hook to do that, but I only want the hook to run once for the entire deployment. I think it will run once from each instance in the deployment group. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: We use Redis to check and acquire an atomic lock, so that subsequent servers that attempt to run the script exit out. Laravel handles it for us, but I believe it basically does the technique documented at https://redis.io/topics/distlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the operation in question is running database scripts, I solved this by adding an additional query that INSERTs the deployment ID (an available environment variable) into a deployment log table. The table enforces uniqueness on the deployment id column, and the script will do nothing if the insert fails.

This has a nice side effect of generating a deployment history inside the application.

Additionally, there's no risk of the "lock" being released too early - it's a permanent lock for each deployment. I am assuming that CodeDeploy will always provide unique deployment ids.

UPDATE: I revisited this later to prevent autoscaling from re-running the database scripts unnecessarily (they deploy the same revision but with different deployment IDs). I now use the aws cli tools () to request the revision information from the CodeDeploy API, and insert that into my database table instead of the deployment ID.